# how to refresh the canvas to display a grid of a changing matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to implement Conway's Game of Life on python 3.10. I want to insert a shape in my grid and see how it evolves. the nextgen function evolves the matrix correctly however I couldn't fine a working way to update the canvas and display my new grid with each generation

Any help is greatly appreciated!

my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *


def makegrid(rows, cols):
    grid = np.zeros((rows, cols), int)
    return grid


def insertpattern(x, y, pattern, grid):
    for i in range(pattern.shape[0]):
        for j in range(pattern.shape[1]):
            grid[x + i][y + j] = pattern[i][j]
    return grid


def enviroment(x, y, grid):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if i == 1 and j == 1:
                continue
            elif (x - 1 + i < 0) or (y - 1 + j < 0) or (x - 1 + i == grid.shape[0]) or (y - 1 + j == grid.shape[1]):
                continue
            else:
                sum += grid[x - 1 + i][y - 1 + j]

    return sum


def nextgen(grid):
    grid2 = makegrid(grid.shape[0], grid.shape[1])
    for i in range(grid.shape[0]):
        for j in range(grid.shape[1]):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                if enviroment(i, j, grid) == 2 or enviroment(i, j, grid) == 3:
                    grid2[i][j] = 1
            elif grid[i][j] == 0:
                if enviroment(i, j, grid) == 3:
                    grid2[i][j] = 1
            else:
                grid2[i][j] = 0

    return grid2


def drawgrid(grid, master, cell_size):
    display = Canvas(master, width=cell_size * grid.shape[1], height=cell_size * grid.shape[0])
    for i in range(grid.shape[0]):
        for j in range(grid.shape[1]):
            fill = "black"
            outline = "grey"
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                fill = "green"
                outline = "grey"
            xmin = j * cell_size
            xmax = xmin + cell_size
            ymin = i * cell_size
            ymax = ymin + cell_size
            display.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)
    return display


ROWS = 20
COLS = 20
CELL_SIZE = 30
grid = makegrid(ROWS, COLS)
pattern = np.ones((3, 1), int)
grid = insertpattern(1, 1, pattern, grid)

app = Tk()
app.title("Game of life")
app.update()
display = drawgrid(grid, app, CELL_SIZE)
display.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried `display.update_idletasks()`, or `display.update()`?

Comment: yes I already tried both of these didn't work

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to create a new `Canvas` for every iteration. Instead, make one canvas and clear it when you want to draw the grid again.

```
def drawgrid(display, grid, cell_size):
    display.delete("all") # Delete current grid
    for i in range(grid.shape[0]):
        ... # The rest of this is the same as before
    # You can also remove "return display"

ROWS = 20
COLS = 20
CELL_SIZE = 30
grid = makegrid(ROWS, COLS)
pattern = np.ones((3, 1), int)
grid = insertpattern(1, 1, pattern, grid)

app = Tk()
app.title("Game of life")
display = Canvas(app, width=CELL_SIZE * grid.shape[1], height=CELL_SIZE * grid.shape[0])
display.pack()
for i in range(30):
    grid = nextgen(grid)
    drawgrid(display, grid, CELL_SIZE)
    display.update()
app.mainloop()
```